# Nontrivial intersection of p-Sylows in proving G is not simple

Tags: group-theory

I just checked many many questions considering this subject but couldn't find a general answer.

If we're trying to prove that a group G is not simple and we're counting elements. In my book it says that we cannot in general (in particular if we have p-Sylows with order >1) assume the intersection of all p-Sylows for given p (say $\bigcap_iP_i$ for $i\in \{1,...,s_p(G)\}$) to be trivial. I understand that we cannot do this in general, but if the intersection wasn't trivial, then $\bigcap_i P_i$ was a normal subgroup of G. How can G be simple then?

Comment: Why do you think $\;P_1\cap P_2\;$ **would have** to be normal in $\;G\;$ ?

Comment: Ah, I have this theorem in my book that says if p divides $|G|$, then  the intersection of all its p-Sylows is normal in G. So, if $P_1$ and $P_2$ were the only p-Sylows, would it be correct then?

Comment: Oh, you mean $\;P_1,\,P_2\;$ are Sylow $\;p\,-$ groups for the same prime $\;p\;$ , right?  Yet it is impossible that a group has *only two* $\;p\,-$ Sylow subgroups for a given prime $\;p\;$ ....why?!

Comment: Ok, I edited my question now. These were bad examples of mine.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  In general you are correct that, for a given prime $p$, the intersection of all $p$-Sylow subgroups of $G$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.  If this intersection happens to be non-trivial, it then follows that $G$ is not simple.

Comment: I am guessing that the sentence in the book is badly worded. I am sure that the intended meaning is that we cannot say in general that the intersection of any two Sylow $p$-subgroups is trivial.

Comment: Oh well, thank you guys! I think, what confused me was simply a mistake in my further thinking: I thought if the intersection of all p-Sylows must be trivial in order for a group to be simple, then there are $s_p(G)\cdot (p^k-1)+1$ distinct elements in $\bigcup Syl_p(G)$. This of course is not true, since $\bigcap_i P_i \not = \emptyset$ doesn't imply $\bigcap_{j\in J \subsetneq I}P_j \not = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

The unique largest normal $p$-subgroup of a finite group $G$ is $O_p(G)=\cap_{P \in Syl_p(G)}P$. This subgroup does not have to be trivial, depending for example on the prime $p$: $O_2(S_3)=1$, but $O_3(S_3)=A_3$. For a non-abelian simple group, irrespective of the prime $p$, $O_p(G)=1$.